# Cannot download pdf using ipad

Tags: php, ipad, codeigniter

I am using the following function to download pdf file it is working fine when i download it from PC or laptop but when i click on download link using ipad it opens a page with lots of special chracters and I am unable to download the file.

My download function is

```
public function download() {
    $download_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/import";
$filename = $_GET['file'];
    $file = str_replace("..", "", $filename);
    $file = "$download_path/$file";
if (!file_exists($file))
        die("Sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");
    $type = filetype($file);
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    readfile($file);
}
```

Any idea about this error ?

Comment: Make sure the charset matches

Comment: what should be the charset? i am using utf-8

Comment: Make sure that's what your iPad is seeing too.

Comment: How can I make sure it ?

Comment: that seems so unsafe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the issue:

```
$type = filetype($file);
header("Content-type: $type");
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php)

> Possible values are fifo, char, dir, block, link, file, socket and
>   unknown.

Which are not things you want to see in the header. You are probably looking for:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Comment: should i replace content-type with the one you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want **[`finfo_file()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)** and not `filetype()`.